# How do I launch a new app and remove the calling app from any open processes?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an updater for our application and having an issue overwriting the files. Here is a long drawn out example. Test.exe is our main app and update.exe is our updater application. Test.exe needs to launch update.exe and then close test.exe. Update.exe will download the new updates from our website to a temp directory and then copy in the new updates. The problem I have is when Test.exe has an update and I try to copy in the new file it says it can't because test.exe is still in use. I "believe" this happens because test.exe is still running in the appdomain because update.exe was launched from test.exe before I closed that app. So do I try and create a new appdomain and launch update.exe from it or is there some other way I am just not seeing? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

That's much too complicated.

In Test.Exe, as soon as you launch Update.Exe, exit.

In Update.Exe:

1. Throw up a "Please wait" or "One moment please" screen.
2. Download the new update from the web site.
3. Initialize a counter to 0.
4. Try to delete Test.Exe. If there's no exception, skip to step 6.
5. If the counter is less than 30(*), sleep for 2 seconds, then add one and go back to step 3.

   Otherwise, we've waited a full minute and we still can't delete Test.Exe - time to display an error message and abort (exit with error).
6. Test.Exe has been deleted! Install the updated version.
7. Launch Test.Exe, then exit from Update.Exe

The result is that you wait until you're able to delete Test.Exe, but you never wait more than one minute.

(*) Adjust the number of iterations, if your program might take longer than 60 seconds just to exit on slow computers.